# Unable to get score of current signed in player(Google Play Services) with exception 26502: CLIENT_RECONNECT_REQUIRED

Tags: android

I want to get the leaderboard score of the current player. Below is the code snippet i am using.

```
    LeaderboardsClient leaderboardsClient = Games.getLeaderboardsClient(this, GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this));
    leaderboardsClient.loadCurrentPlayerLeaderboardScore(getString(R.string.leaderboard_math_game), LeaderboardVariant.TIME_SPAN_ALL_TIME, LeaderboardVariant.COLLECTION_PUBLIC)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AnnotatedData<LeaderboardScore>>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AnnotatedData<LeaderboardScore>> task) {

                    //this is printing
                    Log.d(TAG, "isComplete");
                    try {
                        //below line is giving exception
                        AnnotatedData<LeaderboardScore> score = task.getResult(ApiException.class);
                        Log.d(TAG, "score: " + score.get().getRawScore());
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "exception catched: " + e.getMessage());
                        //exception was:
                        //26502: CLIENT_RECONNECT_REQUIRED
                    }
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to show the leaderboards/achievements UI, but not request or submit to a leaderboard, you probably did not create the "Linked App" oauth2 client id in the google play console as outlined in the [docs](https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/enabling#step_3_generate_an_oauth_20_client_id)

> Warning: Make sure to record the package name and signing certificate that you configured in this step. Using a different certificate or package name in your application will cause authentication failures.